# R - Splitting character vector so that every unique element is added to a new character vector

Tags: regex, r, vector, strsplit

I have a character vector where single elements contain multiple strings separated by commas. I have obtained this list by extracting it from a data frame, and it looks like this:

```
 [1] "Acworth, Crescent Lake, East Acworth, Lynn, South Acworth"                                                                              
 [2] "Ferncroft, Passaconaway, Paugus Mill"                                                                                                   
 [3] "Alexandria, South Alexandria"                                                                                                           
 [4] "Allenstown, Blodgett, Kenison Corner, Suncook (part)"                                                                                   
 [5] "Alstead, Alstead Center, East Alstead, Forristalls Corner, Mill Hollow"                                                                 
 [6] "Alton, Alton Bay, Brookhurst, East Alton, Loon Cove, Mount Major, South Alton, Spring Haven, Stockbridge Corners, West Alton, Woodlands"
 [7] "Amherst, Baboosic Lake, Cricket Corner, Ponemah"                                                                                        
 [8] "Andover, Cilleyville, East Andover, Halcyon Station, Potter Place, West Andover"                                                        
 [9] "Antrim, Antrim Center, Clinton Village, Loverens Mill, North Branch"                                                                    
[10] "Ashland"
```

I would like to obtain a new character vector whereby every single string is an element within this character vector, i.e.:

```
 [1] "Acworth", "Crescent Lake", "East Acworth", "Lynn", "South Acworth"                                                                              
 [6] "Ferncroft", "Passaconaway", "Paugus Mill", "Alexandria", "South Alexandria"
```

I used the `strsplit()` function, however this returns a list. When I try to turn it into a character vector, it reverts to the old state.

I'm sure this is a really simple problem - any help would be greatly appreciated! thanks!

Comment: Instead of running `as.character`, run `unlist` after you've ran `strsplit`

Comment: How simple! awesome, thank you very much!

Comment: See [the demo](https://ideone.com/o40Qhs). BTW, there are spaces - do you want to get rid of them?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `", "` instead of `","`

Comment: @DavidArenburg: I updated the demo at the link above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your post title suggests you want unique strings, so

```
unique(unlist(strsplit(myvec, split=",")))
```

or

```
unique(unlist(strsplit(myvec, split=", ")))
```

if you always have a space following the comma.

Comment: `", "` instead of `","` and you can add `fixed = TRUE`

Comment: Actually, I do not see a requirement to only keep unique strings, but yes, it can be done like that.

Comment: @DavidArenburg, I guess I wouldn't normally automatically assume that. I'd do a sub() call later to tidy up leading white space.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, I took that from "unique element" in the post title, so if you have "Lake Crescent" twice in the list, you'd only want it once in the output. Drop the unique() if this isn't the desired effect.

Comment: @DavidArenburg, fixed = TRUE? Is that a stackoverflow "thing" distinct from the OP marking the question answered?

Comment: Hmm wut? Have no idea what you want.

Answer (score 4):

You may get rid of the spaces and split the character vector with the `"\\s*,\\s*"` regex and then `unlist` the result:

```
v <- c("Acworth, Crescent Lake, East Acworth, Lynn, South Acworth", "Ferncroft, Passaconaway, Paugus Mill", "Alexandria, South Alexandria",  "Allenstown, Blodgett, Kenison Corner, Suncook (part)", "Alstead, Alstead Center, East Alstead, Forristalls Corner, Mill Hollow", "Alton, Alton Bay, Brookhurst, East Alton, Loon Cove, Mount Major, South Alton, Spring Haven, Stockbridge Corners, West Alton, Woodlands", "Amherst, Baboosic Lake, Cricket Corner, Ponemah",  "Andover, Cilleyville, East Andover, Halcyon Station, Potter Place, West Andover",  "Antrim, Antrim Center, Clinton Village, Loverens Mill, North Branch",  "Ashland" )
s <- unlist(strsplit(v, "\\s*,\\s*"))
```

See the [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/mLplBr)

The regex matches zero or more whitespace symbols (`\s*`) on both sides of `,`, thus trimming the values. This will handle cases even when there is a "wild" space *before* a comma in the initial character vector.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you can also use `scan`, like this:

```
unique(scan(what = "", text = v, sep = ",", strip.white = TRUE))
```

The `strip.white = TRUE` part takes care of any leading or trailing whitespace you may have.

Note: "v" comes from [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34927846/1270695).